# enumitem: topsep got changed when used in a nested list

Tags: spacing, itemize, enumitem

`topsep=0pt` could help reduce vertical space before a `enumitem` list, making the vertical spacing identical to a normal document:

[image]

The space between `reference line` and `1st line of list` is what I hope for. But it doesn't do exactly the same thing when used in a nested list:

[image]

In 2nd case, the space between `label 1` and `label 2` looks perfect to me but the vertical space between `reference line` and `1st line of list` is larger than that of the 1st case. How do I fix it without changing the spacing of the external list?

full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, lipsum, calc}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

{\bf 1st case:}

reference line (in document main body)
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt, label=\bfseries label \arabic*.,
    topsep=0pt, noitemsep
    ]
\item{1st line of list}
\item{2nd line of list}
\end{enumerate}

\vspace{1cm}

{\bf 2nd case:}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt, label=\bfseries label \arabic*.,
    ]
\item{blah}
\item{reference line (in a list)
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt, label=\bfseries (nested) label \arabic*.,
        topsep=0pt, noitemsep
        ]
    \item{1st line of list}
    \item{2nd line of list}
    \end{enumerate}
}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to apply `topsep=0pt,noitemsep` to both the outer and inner itemizations.  In the 2nd example, you only apply it to the inner itemization.

Comment: Off-topic: the `\item` instructions do *not* take arguments delimited by curly braces. Hence, please replace `\item{1st line of list}` with `\item 1st line of list`, etc.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I know the solution, but I also hope to keep the `itemsep` for the outer list. That's why I wrote "fix it without changing the spacing of the external list".

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the solution could be to set the `topsep` of the inner list to the negative `topsep` of the outer list:

```
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt, label=\bfseries label \arabic*.]
\item{
    blah
}
\item{
    \newlength{\negativeSep}
    \setlength{\negativeSep}{-\the\topsep}
    reference line (in a list)

    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt, label=\bfseries (nested) label \arabic*.,
        topsep=\negativeSep, noitemsep]
    \item{1st line}
    \item{2nd line}
    \end{enumerate}
}
\end{enumerate}
```

Now the spacing if the outer list doesn't change while the `topsep` of the inner list is 0:

[image]